# XPath: How to grab multiple strings when doing a string, substring, or another function on text() nodes

Tags: xpath

I want to use XPath to grab a list of modified strings via the text() function

**Example code:**

```
 <div>
        <p>
        Monday 2/4/13
        </p>
        <p>
        Tuesday 2/5/13
        </p>
 </div>
```

Now in this example, if I wanted to grab an array of the text between the

markups, I'd write an expression such as *.//div/p/text()*. However, if I wanted to only grab the dates, I could use a substring-after function, but the code *substring-after(.//div/p/text(), ' ')* only grabs one element. How does I write this expression to grab all the text elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **XPath 2.0**, you can use the function directly in the `text()`:

```
//div/p/substring-after(text(), ' ')
```

In **XPath 1.0**, that cannot be achieved with only one expression because:

- the `substring-after()` function takes a **`string`** as first parameter, not a `node-set`
- a function cannot be specified as a location step (as the 2.0 example above does).

So, in 1.0, your best bet is something like (which you'd have to repeat for each node - notice also it returns just a string):

```
concat(substring-after(//div/p[1]/text(), ' '),
       ' ',
       substring-after(//div/p[2]/text(), ' '))
```

Comment: Is this an XPath 2.0 modification? This method doesn't work. I had tried and retried this method using both Firepath and XPath Checker plugins for Firefox.

Comment: Yeah, that is XPath 2.0. I updated the answer, hope it is clearer now. Check [this demo](http://goo.gl/muNSeS) to see how it works with XPath 2.0.

Comment: Note that there is no way it could possibly be done in XPath 1.0 because it does not have the concept of a "sequence of strings" in its data model / type system.

Comment: This is helpful and clarifies my confusion. Thanks!